# Google Directions for Offline Demo

Tags: maps

We are getting ready for a trade show early next month where we will not have Internet access on the show floor.  We've put together machines with local installations of apache, mysql, etc. and are using host files to mimic the various domains we access.

But, one feature of our software is using Google maps to get directions from one address in the system to another.  In order to show this, I need to be able to spoof a map or two.

I don't need to zoom in or do anything with the map image for the show. Just need to show the rendered map page with the directions list, etc.

I'm not having any luck with browser extensions to capture the entire page to an image. They either crash, or don't get the part of the map below the scroll.

Does anybody have any thoughts on how to get this rigged up for the show - either programatically or using tools that you've tried and found to work?

Amy

Comment: a trade show without internet access? what about wifi?

Comment: Or 3G / Edge / GPRS, etc, (whatever is common in the US)?... Or [tethering](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tethering) with a mobile phone?

Comment: Not my call to make. The boss is setting the budget ;-)  I just have to make things work.

Comment: is he making you take your own sandwiches too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just do a screen capture of the whole page

edit: saw the part about not having luck with browser extensions. On a PC, you can try SnagIt, which has a scroll-and-capture functionality. Or, just do it manually and stitch together in photoshop. It can't be *that* long of a page....